# FineUploader On Leave Handling

Tags: fine-uploader

We are developing a Single Page Application in which we have hash based routing, FineUploader seems to have a functionality where when the user clicks the Browser Back the Upload is canceled, how can we use it on navigation inside our app...

Answer (score 0):

Fine Uploader does *not* cancel an in-progress upload when the user navigates away from the current page. Quite the contrary - it prevents the uploader from being accidentally canceled by popping up a confirm dialog. If you would like to cancel all uploads at any time, you can do so via the [`cancelAll` API method](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/methods.html#cancelAll).

Comment: The default message seems to suggest so "The files are being uploaded, if you leave now the upload will be canceled."